# Github Login (oAuth ) from react- chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am building a simple chrome extension which will make some simple API calls.

For this, I need the user to be logged in with a Github Account, however, if I set up a new oAuth app on github, I need to add `Homepage URL` and `Authorization callback URL` which, as far as I understand, we don't have from a Chrome Extension popup.

IMPORTANT: I don't want to use firebase. All I need is to be able to get the user code, which I can process in my backend after to get the token and all the rest.

Need you help here ! :-)

Here is my background file

```
const GITHUB_AUTHORIZATION_UL = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
const CLIENT_ID = encodeURIComponent("xxxx");
const SCOPE = encodeURIComponent("user:email");

let user_signed_in = false;

function create_auth_endpoint() {
  let endpoint_url = `${GITHUB_AUTHORIZATION_UL}
?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}
&scope=${SCOPE}`;

  return endpoint_url;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {

  if (request.message === 'login') {
      chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
          url: create_auth_endpoint(),
          interactive: true
      }, (response) => {
        console.log(response)
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)
              console.log("Could not authenticate.");
              sendResponse('fail');
          } else {
              user_signed_in = true;
              sendResponse('success');
          }
      });

      return true;
  } else if (request.message === 'logout') {
      user_signed_in = false;

      sendResponse('success');
  }
});
```

And my login handler from popup.tsx

```
  const handleLogin = () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'login' }, function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      if (response === "success") {
        window.close();
      }
  });
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "test ext",
  "description": "test ext",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "favicon-32.png",
    "48": "favicon-32.png",
    "128": "favicon-32.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "test ext",
    "default_icon": "favicon-32.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "identity"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with various options for the requested url for github such as : http://chrome-extension://CHROME_ID/popup.html
=> This fails directly.

Interestingly, if I just input https://www.google.com, I have a popup with the github login, then I am directly to google and it fail.
However, the extension authorization is added as "accepted" in my github account.

Here is my log from the background for response :
`{message: 'The user did not approve access.'}`eventhough I approved it. Once I am redirected to the popup with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it fails

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I have a similar issue